# MacBook reboots during Debian installation

Tags: bootcamp, startup, unix, dual-boot

I'm trying to install Debian on my MacBook Pro (late 2013):

1. prepare a bootable usb: `$ sudo dd if=path_to/debian-live-12.0.0-amd64-xfce.iso of=/dev/sda`
2. plug in usb drive and reboot MacBook:

[image]

The installer is loaded then it just reboot after a few seconds (before I did anthing). I try several times rebooting into installation page but it still reboot after clicking "start installer".

Did I trigger some protection mechanism? If so, how do I turn them off to install Linux on it?

Comment: There’s nothing on a Mac (especially that vintage) that will “block” Linux from installing.  Usually when you see a reboot in the middle of an installation like that is usually due to a hardware issue - it causes some sort of crash during the hardware probe.  I saw this with 2011 MBPs and their faulty GPUs - FreeBSD/Linux would probe the GPU and it would restart.

Comment: @Allan my laptop is without GPU so it could be a different problem than yours

Comment: That was meant as an example, not a diagnosis of your issue